# generic typetrait to convert to string or double

Tags: c++, type-traits

I need a type trait to convert input to string or double. Now I have something like this:

```
template<typename T> struct SH_trait{ };
template<> struct SH_trait<float>{ typedef double type; };
template<> struct SH_trait<double>{ typedef double type; };
template<> struct SH_trait<char*>{ typedef std::string type; };
template<> struct SH_trait<const char*>{ typedef std::string type; };
template<std::size_t N> struct SH_trait<const char[N]> { typedef std::string type; };
template<std::size_t N> struct SH_trait<char[N]> { typedef std::string type; };
template<> struct SH_trait<std::string>{ typedef std::string type; };
template<> struct SH_trait<TString>{ typedef std::string type; };
```

and I am using it as

```
void f(T input) {
  SH_trait<T>::type myvalue(input);
  Class template_class(myvalue);
  ...
}
```

I am doing it because template_class is specialized only for `double` and `string`.

the point is: suppose that the user use for example `int`. I want to convert it to double, so I have to add another line. Is it possibile to write something more generic to cover all the cases?

**no c++11, no boost, only c++03**

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a base template that has an `std::string` typedef. And then you can specialize for all other integral types using SFINAE:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct SH_trait
{
    typedef std::string type;
};

template <typename T>
struct SH_trait<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
{
    typedef double type;
};

static_assert( std::is_same<SH_trait<int>::type, double>::value ); // doesn't run
```

[Here it's a test program.](http://ideone.com/O6JrKq)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your type is implicitly convertible to `double` and use `std::string` otherwise:

```
template<bool isit> struct convertible
{
  typedef std::string type;
};

template<> struct convertible<true>
{
  typedef double type;
};

template<typename T>
void f(T input) 
{
  Class<convertible<std::is_convertible<T, double>::value>::type> template_class(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T> 
struct SH_trait {
   typedef
   std::conditional<
       std::is_convertible<T,double>::value,
       double,
       std::string
   >::type 
   type;
}
```

How do you want to handle case if T is not convertible to double and std::string?

Comment: I forgot to say: no c++11

Comment: in case T is not convertible to double or string I would like to have a compile error assertion, or something similar.